# Why is dompdf not honoring the specified page size?

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

I'm trying to create a PDF using dompdf version 0.6.1 (latest at the time of writing) and am stuck at very initial step, the page size. I'm trying to create `A4` size PDF. Following is my markup

```
$html = <<<HTML
<html>
    <head>
       <style>
          @page {size: 21cm 29.7cm; margin: 0;}
       </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        testing
    </body>
</html>
HTML;


  $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
  $dompdf->set_paper('a4', 'portrait');
  $dompdf->load_html($html);
  $dompdf->render();

  $dompdf->stream("title.pdf");
```

The PDF is created but it is always `32.07cm` wide. I've tried to play around with dompdf DPI settings by overriding the `DOMPDF_DPI` constant but it only affects the content scaling, not the page size. Setting `size` CSS property value to `a4` doesn't help either.

I've exhausted my searching options but havn't found a solution. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Update**
The *duplicate* question doesn't have an accepted answer and the better looking among the two answers has following as a solution

```
$dompdf->set_paper(array(0, 0, 595, 841), 'portrait');
```

the array parameter provided to `DOMPDF::set_paper()` is just an alternative representation of `A4` size in points. I've tried it and it doesn't work. The actual issue here is that no matter how one sets the paper size, the PDF size is always 152% of it.

**Update 2**
I'm having same issue as "Kornel N" writes in this forum post https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dompdf/I_j6R4_9ZwA

> > I switched to dompdf recently, I was using ufpdf before. I got used to the size of an `A4` document when creating some invoices with tables.
> >
> > Now, when I set the paper size to `A4` (`$dompdf->set_paper('a4', 'portrait');`) I get a much bigger area.
> >
> > I extended the `write_log` method with the paper size, it says it's `A4`, as I set it.
> >
> > The `cpdf_adapter.cls.php` file states the size of the `A4` is `595.28,841.89 points`, as I got used to it.
> >
> > When I open the generated pdf with pdf reader software, it says it's size is `8.27 x 11.69in`, that is the size of an `A4` sheet.
> >
> > Still, when I try to draw a rectangle to fill the sheet (just a div with a 1px border) I have to make it `791px x 1101px` big to match the paper size.
> >
> > The bottom border is then about `20px` from the bottom of the page, but if I try to increase the height of the div dompdf just adds one more blank page to the document, like there was an invisible bottom margin for the div, or padding for the page. There is no such, because I set it in the css.
> >
> > ```
> > @page { margin: 0in 0in 0in 0in;} 
> > .oldal{width:791px; height:1101px;  border:1px solid red;}
> > ```
> >
> > Please, help me, why is that happening? Is this size OK or should it be as defined?

Comment: @MateiMihai thanks for trying to help but the solutions of the "duplicate" question do not solve my issue. The page still remains `32.07cm` wide

Comment: which version of dompdf?

Comment: @BrianS I'm using dompdf version 0.6.1.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, just FYI, the DPI does not affect physical units (e.g. centimeters or inches)

Comment: Is your problem that the actual page size as presented is wrong or that you're trying to fill the space of the page and the element is paging?

Comment: (I ask because it appears to me that the page is the expected size.)

Comment: @BrianS I think the page is wider than expected. I'm using a very simple method of verifying that. I take a screenshot of generated PDF on 100% and measure that in Photoshop setting Photoshop's ruler units to centimeters. Photoshop says it's `32.07cm` wide.

Comment: I'm still having this (and many others) with dompdf library and am still looking for solutions :(

Comment: I'm not sure that's the best way to determine the PDF dimensions. The native resolution of a PDF is 72 PPI (points being the native PDF unit). If your monitor resolution (in DPI) is different then I think what you see on the screen won't necessarily match up with the actual dimensions. Since you have access to Photoshop just open the document directly and check the dimensions.

Comment: @John Conde did you even read my question carefully before marking it as **duplicate of the question that I have mentioned in my question as unhelpful**? That question has no valid answers and my question is different than that.

Comment: Do you have an example document you can share? Using Photoshop (or Illustrator for that matter) is not a good way to diagnose a PDF file. Use Adobe Acrobat or a dedicated PDF inspection tool. I'd be happy to take a look at the document if you can link to one I can download.

Answer (score 0):

`dompdf` uses [points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)) as measuring unit.

you could try some [online cm to point converters](http://www.unitconversion.org/typography/centimeters-to-points-computer-conversion.html) to get the measurement

so for  size: 21cm 29.7cm; you could try

```
   $dompdf->setPaper([0,0,595.275590551,841.88976378])
```

Comment: please reply if this helped you..@Ejaz